# how to change smslib outbound text

Tags: sendmessage, smslib

I change the message as you can see on my codes but the receiver receives different message. as you can see on my results below the message sent was "test message". pls pls need help:(

```
    OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
    System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
    System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
    System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1","COM6",115200, "Huawei", "");
    gateway.setInbound(true);
    gateway.setOutbound(true);
    gateway.setSimPin("0000");

    Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
    Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
    Service.getInstance().startService();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Modem Information:");
    System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
    System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
    System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
    System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
    System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
    System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
    System.out.println();
    // Send a message synchronously.
    OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("09085928249", "que onda como andas!");
    Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
    System.in.read();
    Service.getInstance().stopService();
}
```

result

```
 Gateway Id: modem.com1
 Message Id: 0
 Message UUID: eeecf9ba-5cb6-49f3-a20f-4e1901e2527a
 Encoding: 7-bit
 Date: Thu Jan 26 18:24:18 CST 2017
 SMSC Ref No: 95
 Recipient: +639085928249
 Dispatch Date: Thu Jan 26 18:24:22 CST 2017
 Message Status: SENT
 Failure Cause: NO_ERROR
 Validity Period (Hours): -1
 Status Report: false
 Source / Destination Ports: -1 / -1
 Flash SMS: false
 Text: Test Message
 PDU data: D4F29C0E6A96E7F3F0B90C
 Scheduled Delivery: null
```

Comment: Are you sure `Service` is singleton - you seem to call `getInstance()` too many times.

Comment: yes its singleton

Comment: the only problem was the text message. whenver i send sms it keeps on sending "Test Message"